# Difference between openvswitch_agent and ml2_agent, (Mitaka)

Tags: openstack, openvswitch

I'm new in the OpenStack world.

I've a doubt: I'm trying to install OpenStack Mitaka (controller, network, compute), but I don't know which file I have to configure in `/neutron/plugins/ml2/` between `openvswitch_agent.ini` and `ml2_agent.ini`.

How can I set OpenStack in order to use a specified file between `openvswitch_agent.ini` and `ml2_agent.ini`?

Aren't they equivalent?

Comment: Grat, your first post here is quite good. A little advice: please try to formulate the title as a clear question, before my fix it looked more like a tag cloud. But it is even now not really meaningful.

Comment: Well, maybe your question will be still closed, because people think it matches better the profile of http://serverfault.com . If it would happen, give them a try. (Or to http://unix.stackexchange.com, there is much nicer people.)

Comment: Thank you for your impression! I'm new in this world!

Comment: My pleasure. Please, now edit the title of your question to a clear, questioning sentence.